# Two different SSL Sites with same name possible in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, ssl-certificate

I just upgraded from debian 7 to debian 8 (apache 2.4) box called debian.domain.com
I have Request Tracker, a helpdesk software, and i want to run it from https://helpdesk.domain.com (i have a valid SSL certificate for it)

The proper dns to resolve helpdesk.domain.com to debian.domain.com is already setup and works fine.

I have a small php script that serves firefox updates over plain http, and i also have a pub folder in /var/www that contains the flash player updates. This one MUST be served over https.

The question is: can i server both the helpdesk and the flash updates from helpdesk.domain.com?

Helpdesk files are in /opt/rt4/share/html and the /pub folder is at /var/www.

So far i can get the following to work:

-Firefox updates are working from plain old http

-Flash updates are being server over helpdesk.domain.com just fine

-Helpdesk is accesible from debian.domain.com only, thus a certificate
   error is received

Here's my current apache 2.4 config, can someone help me tune it to achieve this if possible? Somehow i think Debian 7 was working fine, but i am not sure:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin fjleon@domain.com
    ServerName debian.domain.com:443

    <Directory "/opt/rt4/sbin">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/domain.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/root_bundle.crt

    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

    ScriptAlias / /opt/rt4/sbin/rt-server.fcgi/

    DocumentRoot "/opt/rt4/share/html"
    <Location />
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
        Options +ExecCGI
        AddHandler fcgid-script fcgi
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin fjleon@domain.com
    ServerName helpdesk.domain.com:443
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/domain.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/root_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Here's the old config that i used on Debian 7 (apache 2.2), however i tried using it with this version and the same thing happens

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin fleon@domain.com
    ServerName debian.domain.com:443
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    DocumentRoot /opt/rt4/share/html
    Alias /NoAuth/images/ /opt/rt4/share/html/NoAuth/images/
    ScriptAlias / /opt/rt4/sbin/rt-server.fcgi/
    <Location />
      ## Apache version < 2.4
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Location>
    <Location /NoAuth/images >
    </Location>
    <Directory "/opt/rt4/sbin">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain/root_bundle.crt
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin fleon@domain.com
    ServerName helpdesk.domain.com:443
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain/root_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Update: here's my 000-default.conf file which is used for plain http. A redirect wouldn't work because the flash client requests https directly according to the Adobe documentation [1](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flashplayer/pdfs/flash_player_21_0_admin_guide.pdf). My ssl config is called rt.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            #AllowOverride None
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: removing :443 from ServerName should help

Comment: Please clarify what "This one MUST be served over https." means. Is http disallowed to work? Please post your full configuration. The configuration for http is missing.

Comment: removing :443 from which server name? The flash client from Adobe connects to helpdesk.domain.com only through https. Do you still need the http config? It is the standard 000-default.conf that comes with apache anyway

Answer (score 0):

Please post your full configuration. The configuration for http is missing. If i had to guess, you have to to the following:

1. Change the `ServerName` entries to the following:

   ServerName helpdesk.domain.com
2. Ensure that your configuration for `helpdesk.domain.com` is not the first read by Apache. If they are in different files, Apache will read them in alphanumerical ascending order. The default `000-default.conf` on Debian usually does the job.
3. For ensuring https for some files, either `mod_redirect` or `mod_alias`(using the `Redirect`directive will do the job. See also see [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect). Please clarify what "This one MUST be served over https." means. Is http disallowed to work?

Comment: i only have the standard 000-default.conf config for http that comes with apache, and one other file that is the whole file i posted in the question. i will try removing the :443 from the helpdesk.domain.com, however i don't see on paper how it should help. What is driving me crazy is that i think this worked on debian 7. I will post back

Comment: can i somehow create a symlink in /opt/rt4/share/html called pub which points to /var/www/pub and exclude my helpdesk from processing it with its fastcgi handler?

Comment: Please open a new question regarding that point. I can also recommend reading [this documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#directory) first.